# How do I create a login "string" that contains 2 embedded nulls, and the login and password character strings?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am trying to accomplish the end as coded in this pseudo code:

```
NSString *login;
NSString *pass;
<snip>

NSString *loginString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\000%@\000%@", login, pass];
```

...and as you can imagine I get the Warning: "CFString literal contains NUL character."
I completely understand why. I have forced a null char into my string.  What I need some help on is how to accomplish this goal with correct Obj-C code. Curiously, the code as-is actually works, but I know it is a problem waiting to happen with that warning.

Note- the character length of "login" and "pass" is not known in advance, could be different at different times.  So that eliminates some sort of a static solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want those nulls there, but if you only need to concatenate the password to the user, simply use `NSString *loginString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", login, pass];`

Comment: Ruben, thank you. I had also previously tried your suggestion, but as you will agree that suggestion eliminates the required nulls in the string. They are required to be there.  It is not about why I need them, but as I do, then how to accomplish to goal of the pseudo code that employs them. Suggestions and help still open and welcomed to this unresolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
unsigned short nullChar[] = {0};
NSString *nullCharSeparator = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:nullChar length:sizeof(nullChar) encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF16LE)];
```

(taken from http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/174917-nul-characters-in-nsstring-cause-unexpected-results.html)

Then something like this:

```
NSString *loginAndNull = [login stringByAppendingString:nullCharSeparator];
NSString *loginAndPass = [loginAndNull stringByAppendingString:password];
```

Comment: that looks to be an interesting solution. I had just decided to "accept" the warning msg but this is better. I'll try it and get back. Thx for the time.